# How to Find/Change logo on main page?

Tags: magento-1.8, design

I'm trying to change a logo by a website developer...they no longer answer our calls and I really need help.  I found the area of the backend that allows you to change your logo, but i have no clue how to upload the picture because i see no upload button......or if its uploaded from a website i have no idea what website it is..is there a way to override or change everything so I can add on my own files from my computer?
1.
[image: first step screenshot]

[image: 2nd step screen shot]

larger size screenshots 
step1
[IMG]http://i60.tinypic.com/2ngtwg5.jpg[/IMG]

step2
[IMG]http://i57.tinypic.com/20ae7ti.jpg[/IMG]

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the logo, you need to upload one via ftp to your active theme:

> Magento_Root/skin/frontend/default/Active_Theme/images

Place the file **your_theme_logo.png** in the above directory.

In **Logo Image Link** Enter **images/your_theme_logo.png**

Flush your cache:

System -> Cache Management

Press CTRL+F5 in your web browser and the new logo will appear.

Comment: Hi! thank you so much for your quick response.... i currently found an ftp called filezilla....could you possibly show me how to upload this via ftp to my active theme? or could you recommend an ftp that you are comfortable with? sorry this is my first time doing this!

Comment: You need to contact your hosting provider and get the details to gain access to your files. You need a username, password and the server ftp address. Unfortunately this goes beyond the scope of your question. If this has solved your issue, please hit the check mark to accept this as an answer. Good luck!

Comment: is your issue resolved

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Log into your Magento Admin Panel

Step 2 : Go to System ->> Configuration

Step 3 : Click on "Design" in the left side menu panel

Step 4 : Open the "Header" section

Step 5 : Change the file name in the "Logo Image Src" to the file name you just uploaded. Leave the images/prefix alone

Step 6 : Click "Save Config"